# Dio interceptor problem with Laravel Sanctum (CSRF)

Tags: laravel, flutter, dio, laravel-sanctum, csrf-token

I'm new in flutter and I'm trying to implement the registration account on an REST API that I already have using Laravel + Sanctum and I'm having some problems with CSRF Token.

I code an interceptor to inject the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` to the request headers.

This is my interceptor

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class CsrfTokenInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final Dio dio;

  CsrfTokenInterceptor(this.dio);

  @override
  Future<void> onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    List<String> methods = <String>['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH'];

    if (methods.contains(options.method)) {
      final response = await dio.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.noContent) {
        response.headers.forEach((name, values) {
          if (name == HttpHeaders.setCookieHeader) {
            for (String value in values) {
              String key = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('=')).trim();

              if (key == 'XSRF-TOKEN') {
                Cookie cookie = Cookie.fromSetCookieValue(value);
                options.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = Uri.decodeFull(cookie.value);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }

    return handler.next(options);
  }
}
```

and when run a post on `http://my-api/register` I'm having this on the `curl_logger_dio_interceptor`.

```
[log] curl -i \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: eyJpdiI6Ik0rc0FGRWJPdDAyQTI4bTdIVUpXUkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoidzdaNUZyTUhsT2NUa0l3NXZ4dERmelQrR2ljc2RCZ3g0WllwSmh1NmpxTDFmd2F6Y2tMSFBxUVl4eEl0Rk1kb1Q0UE9xU05ETkdFaTVwc3FDNzl1S0tqRStDWmhiczBYc3JRZ2JSOG8vZFZjU1ZpYW9xM3NkWTh2eE9OQ2FzeTIiLCJtYWMiOiI1ODhjMjM5MDdkYTI2MWYyMmYwN2ZlYTlhZDg3OWFlYWZiZDc3OTA1ZTk4MDNlNTU0OWM1ODE2NzE5YmQ0ZWUzIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=" \
    -H "content-length: 103" \
    -d "\"{\\"email\\":\\"email@domain.com\\",\\"password\\":\\"12345678\\",\\"device_name\\":\\"6E7D7E70-501B-4594-ABAF-0D3826B5CE6B\\"}\"" \
    "http://my-api/register"
```

and the server answer is: `{"message":"CSRF token mismatch."}`

But when I run the same thing on Postman works fine!

Someone can help me?

Comment: I'd run it in the debugger and make sure the lines below are doing what you think they should.                          Cookie cookie = Cookie.fromSetCookieValue(value);
                options.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN

Comment: The lines are doing the job, you can check the X-XSRF-TOKEN header in the cURL being passed as a parameter, even doing a debug on the API side, I'm getting the token!